# Input field alignment

Tags: css

I have an email input field that has to be aligned in the center of the page. I have tried using alignment, but it wouldn't align the input field. I can align the text in the input field, but not the physical input field.

Comment: Can you provide us with Minimal, Reproducible Example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
"input" element is inline-element.
<div>
  <input type="email" style="text-align:center" value="text is center"/>
</div>

this align the text in the input field.
you should be put style to parent.

<div style="text-align:center">
  <input type="email" value="input box is center"/>
</div>

of course - "input" element should inline type.
if you changed "input" element's display type
try to other way. 

<div>
  <input type="email" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;" value="input box is center"/>
</div>
or 
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
  <input type="email" style="display:block;" value="input box is center"/>
</div>
```